# How is a normal map applied to a triangle mesh?

Tags: normal-mapping, obj

I'm working on writing my own parser/renderer for the `obj` file type, and right now I have it working so that I can draw the model correctly and use the `vt` texture coordinates to apply a texture to the model. The next step that I want to do is apply a normal map to make the surface look smoother, but I'm not completely sure how this is done.

I've applied normal maps to a sphere before, and part of the trouble that I had in implementing that was figuring out how to get a consistent pair of tangent vectors in order to adjust the normal. On a sphere, that's done using spherical coordinates and calculating dp/du and dp/dv, but how is it done in an `obj` file? It seems like local coordinates, normal coordinates, and texture coordinates are the only thing stored for each vertex, no tangent vectors. I know that the surface can also be smoothed by interpolating the normal vectors defined at each vertex, but the model I'm working with doesn't even have those defined. And I know it *should* be possible with the model because if I open it in the windows 3d viewer I can see that it smooths out the triangles.

How are the tangent vectors found on a triangle mesh? In case it matters, the specific model that I'm using is one that I [downloaded from here](https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/character/woman/juliette-10781-sport-girl-free-3dpeople-model).

Comment: A popular method for calculating tangent vectors is the [MikkTSpace](http://mikktspace.com/) algorithm - [we have existing Q&A on the topic you might like to review](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=mikktspace). Once you've read up on this, if you have any trouble applying it to your case, can you edit your question to highlight the specific problem you need help solving?

Comment: Thank you for the link, that should be helpful! I was trying to find any resources online for how to do it and couldn't find anything.